# How can I assign values to variables from different spans with the same ID

Tags: javascript

I have many spans with the same ID. how can assign their values to different variables in order of their occurance.

Ex

```
<span id="hello"> 18</span>
<span id="hello"> 12</span>
<span id="hello"> 21</span>
```

I want var1 = 18  var2= 12  var3= 21

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use classes instead. Duplicate IDs only mean trouble. And imo it would be better to create an array of values than "dynamic variables".

Comment: @Felix: Only true if that attribute is of ID type, which we can't formally know without seeing either DTD or Schema. It probably is though, as that looks a lot like HTML…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my comment regarding IDs. Now assuming you give that elements a class `hello` instead, this will work in all browsers:

```
var values = [],
    spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(var i = 0, l = spans.length; i < l; i++) {
    var span = spans[i];
    if(span.className === 'hello') {
        values.push(span.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/rzaLw/)

If you can't change the HTML, in this case you can compare the IDs:

```
if(span.id === 'hello')
```

This is ok, because we are iterating over all spans. But methods like `getElementById` won't work!

Comment: Thanks for that. I cant give them a class because this webpage is generated by a premitive software i am using. im just trying to 'hack' at it. is there another way to target the spans without using classname?

Comment: @user521180: Well in that case you actually can use the IDs. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

The id tag is supposed to be unique within a document. If you are trying to give them the same style, then you should use the class attribute instead of the id attribute. You can use the [jQuery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector) to get all elements with a given class (assuming you change to using class instead of id).